# Character bone not bending after adding pole target

Tags: bones

I have this bone series

[image]

and as you can see, the bone is bending nicely. however, i wanted a pole target, so i added one in front of the knee.

heres what happens now:

[image]
[image]

its not bending, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem. You need to have some small angle of rotation in the leg bones. The IK solver fails when the bones are completely straight.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your knee joint is not straight like this.
[image]

Instead, make it bent a little and all will be well. Just like in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Would be good if you could add *why* the pole needs this to work correctly.